# Android wear rogue app listening for path variable - how to defend against

Tags: android, wear-os

Let's imagine i have a android wear app that extends my app.  Now i ship my app and the user is using it.  The app sends a message to all connected nodes like this:

//eg. to send a string to all connected nodes on an android wear network:

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( apiClient ).await();
String myMessage= "A cool Message";
for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
   MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
         apiClient, node.getId(), path, myMessage.getBytes() ).await();
//where path variable can be a string such as “/cool_message”
}
```

and alls fine in the world since only connected nodes can get the message and they must know the path variable which is "/cool_message"

now lets say there is a rogue app which also has a wearable and its a connected node. and lets say its not filtering for path, so it gets ALL MESSAGES when it listens.  How do i protect other wearable apps from seeing my message .  The rogue wearable apps listening code would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startIntent.putExtra("DATA", messageEvent.getData());
        startActivity(startIntent);

}
```

notice i have no call to **`if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(“/cool_message”))`** here. so the rogue wearable can listen for ANY message. How do i not broadcast my message to this node ? is there a defense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wear framework delivers messages between apps that are signed with the same cert and have identical package names, so only your app can see the messages that is being sent by your app on a different node, regardless of the path, etc. So if two apps, signed with two different certs, use the same path, each can only see their own message.